# How to structure the database if users can have many entries in tables?

Tags: mysql

I'm planning a project right now where an user from my service can login and manage his clients, etc. Overall there are 10-15 different tables, where every user has their own clients and the clients have their own data. My first intention was to create a table "users" and a table "clients" and have a column in "clients" named "userID" to assign the clients to the user. The data in the other tables would be assigned by "clientID".

But then I thought "*Wouldn't it be very inperformant when I have like 1000 users registered and they all have 3000 clients?*" that would be 3 million entries in "clients" to look through when I only want to list the clients for 1 User for example.

My second intention then was to create a database from a fixed template every time a user registered. That would mean, every user has his own database. Is this better? Even worse? Is there a plan C?

What would you suggest me to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: worrying amount millions of rows isn't you problem, and its still small in MySQL terms. Do you ever treat all clients as a group? What sorts of queries?

Comment: If a user can manage several clients and a client can be managed by several users, your model has to be ```User``` -> ```User_Client``` <- ```Client``` where ```User_Client``` consists of {User_Id, Client_Id}. And the volume of data you are talking about is not really  huge for a database

Comment: I mostly treat them as a group, yes. But not all the time. The querys are not that complex. Simple SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETEs

Comment: Do you think that having 1000 databases is better than having one table with 3 million rows? What happens if you get 10000 users? Will you manage 10000 databases?